# Can anyone identify these bugs in the soil?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]I was checking the soil around my pineapple pear tree and found this living down in the dirt. My goal is to identify the insect so I can properly treat the soil in an organic manner.

Comment: This what? W/o a pick it's hard to answer the question :-) also add your whereabouts and the habitat

Comment: Could you provide your location please

Comment: They look like termites.

Comment: It would be better if you posted a close-up.

Comment: Mention size in the description. At least approximate.

Comment: How do they behave ? How do they move ?